# How do I conditionally sum a cell based on the value of another cell?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, sum, ifs

I have a terrible formula that looks like this:

`=if(B17="Yes",B$7)+if(C17="Yes",C$7)+if(D17="Yes",D$7)+if(E17="Yes",E$7)+if(F17="Yes",F$7)`

I'd also like to be able to expand it if I go longer than column F.

Basically, other people can change their own row, in this example row 17, but there are many many rows just like it.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YKCaGKVmiqfJQz9RcLiLOFXVpUqScNXcYOkPVSOVKz4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/SUM(IF(B17:W17="yes", B$7:W$7, )))))
```

---

### update

or delete everything in Y17:Y and use this on Y17:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/MMULT(IF(B17:W="yes", B7:W7, 0), SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(B:W), 1, 1, )))))
```

[image]

Comment: @VillAin see the updated answer

Comment: The initial answer worked, I solved the circular dependency by moving the cell containing the formula around